# No Such Bean definition Found -Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an external jar file which is added as a dependency to another Web application.When i run this Jar file stand alone it works fine.

When i include this in my web application i get the following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'inviteAuditService': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type
>   [com.trunym.certificateserver.datajpa.repository.InviteAuditRepository]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=,
>   name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   com.trunym.medallion.datajpa.factory.AbstractServiceFactory.getMedallionFactoryInstance(AbstractServiceFactory.java:14)
>     at
>   com.trunym.medallion.web.controller.ManageBadgeController.getHomePage(ManageBadgeController.java:27)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type
>   [com.trunym.certificateserver.datajpa.repository.InviteAuditRepository]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=,
>   name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:438)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
>     ... 47 more

Here is my application context from the Web application :

```
<import resource="classpath*:certificate-server-context.xml" />

<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:medallion-config.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="%{" />
        <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
    </bean>


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <value>
                resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.medallion.web.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <task:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Well...where do you have a `InviteAuditRepository` bean declared?

Comment: I have that declared in the external jar file called `cerserv.jar` .This contains the imported resource `certificate-server-context.xml`.In this `InviteAuditService` has `InviteAuditRepository` autowired in it

Comment: Where is the `certificate-server-context.xml` located in that `jar`?

Comment: The exact location is `WEB-INF\lib\cerserv.jar\certificate-server-context.xml` Inside the war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to resolve the issue,The issue was that i had conflicting package names in my web app and the external jar.

And the context component scan was giving the problem.